# Get Amplify's Environment Variables on Vite React

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, vite

How do I get Amplify's Environment Variable on a Vite React application? I've tried console logging to the import.meta.env, but only the process_env is showing. What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you share the environment variable names here?

Comment: Hi Sir @AllanChua, we've found out the reason why. We apparently had to rebuild the app in order for the env variable to show.

Comment: OK cool! I've just placed a common problem with `VITE_` environment variables just in case somebody would need it moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please rename your environment variables so that they'd start with `VITE_` prefix. According to the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html), any environment variable that does not start with `VITE_` will not be exposed on the browser side for the purpose of preventing accidental leaking of variables.

Comment: Yes sir, as per the documentation, we need to add the VITE_ prefix on the environment. The problem was that the environment variables were added after the build.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it wasn't showing was that we added the environment variable AFTER the build. In order for the environment variable to show, you have to declare it first before building.